# angular params and express hits wrong req url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

anytime I add a param or query on any angular route, my browser request adds that param to the url request for my css file as such.

I am using html5mode true (pretty urls)

```
.state('profile', {
    url: "/profile/:steamId",
    templateUrl: "app/profile/profile.html",
    controller: "ProfileCtrl",
    controllerAs: "profile",
    data: {
        contentPages: 1
    }
});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

My angular service

```
    getProfile:function(steamId){
        var self = this;
        return $http.get('api/user/'+steamId).then(function(response){
            $log.debug('getProfile', response.data);
            return response.data;
        }, function(err){
            $log.error('Error user', err);
        });
    },
```

and in my server

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Launch ======================================================================

var server = app.listen(8000, function(){
    logger.info('The dagger flies at 8000');
});

// Configuration ======================================================================

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Routes ======================================================================

var users = require('./routes/users.route')(passport, logger);

// Middleware ======================================================================

app.use('/api/users', users);

app.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: 'public' });
});
```

my index.html is set up for this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="builds/style.css"/>
```

Normally I see something like this in my network tab when I'm on localhost:8000/profile for example

```
http://localhost:8000/builds/style.css
```

but when I add a param like this

```
localhost:8000/profile/13456
```

In my network tab, I see this

```
http://localhost:8000/profile/builds/style.css
```

and therefore a bunch of unstyled html code.

How can I fix this? I have tried playing around with the express static middleware but no success.

Comment: because you are referring `href="builds/style.css"` which tries to load resource from current address. Try changing it to `href="/builds/style.css"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linking CSS or JavaScript is relative to your current directory. To overcome that, add a `/` in front of the path to reference it as absolute path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/builds/style.css"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. However, I'm still not sure why this works with routes I have currently and not routes with params. Any explanation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Ohp, never mind I understand now after messing around with it some more. Thanks a lot. cheers